# Asp.net core 3.1 identity roles getting deleted

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, roles

I am having an issue with identity roles in ASP.Net core 3.1. The data inside the AspNetRoleUserRoles keeps getting deleted.

I am not able to find out what is causing it. Is there a way to log these actions, and figure out where is the action is coming from.

Comment: 1) You can try to debug your project and check Console logs, pay more attention to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command` related logs and Query about `DELETE FROM [AspNetUserRoles]...` etc 2) Please check if some custom trigger deleting records in [AspNetUserRoles] table.

Comment: You have to give a little more context. When are they deleted? Are they even persisted? Which actions are you performing before they are getting deleted? Are you using the RoleManager?

Comment: @sprengo yes i am using the RoleManager and they are persisted in the db

Comment: Do you try to find some useful information from logs?

Comment: You need to provide useful information about your use case. About the circumstances which lead to the deletion.

Comment: @FeiHan I am not sure where to add the logs

Comment: @sprengo I am not sure what is causing the delete that’s why I am lost

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by having a modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new RoleConfiguration()); in the ApplicationDbContext class.

Everytime the container will renetialize the roles where re-written and the previous roles got discarted.